# Azure DevOps: Distribution of Story Points / Feature / Sprint

Tags: charts, azure-devops

I'm trying to get an good overview of the story points distribution in a sprint (both current and older)
What I'd like to see is how many story points there is on each feature that is worked on in a sprint.

I'd like to show it as a Pie chart with the total sum of Story points in center, each feature in a different color with the sum of story points shown on the feature - all related to the specific sprint.

Comment: There is no built-in chart that can show this. You'll need to dive into PowerBI or another reporting tool. One thing that intrigues me is why you'd want this... Ideally you'd work on as few features as you can and are you spending the bulk of your teams capacity on one thing, finish it and then move on to the next one.

Comment: Thank you @jessehouwing
I agree on the Ideally statement - and I was hoping to use this illustration of data to highlight the problem and thereby get closer to the best scenario

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a query like the following and add `story points` field through `Column options`.

[image]

Then save the query, new chart in `Charts` option.

[image]

Currently, only such a pie chart can be implemented in azure devops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid it only takes me some of the way.
I need to GroupBy Parent to have the sum of story points for each feature.
And it seems it is not possible to do so with charts

Again thank you

Comment: You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.